# How to send several notifications to a specific while deploying a system?

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to send a notification to a specific user. It works on my localhost and I can send as many notifications to a user as I want, but when I try to deploy it, I can only send 1 notification to a specific user. When I try to send a notification again to the same user I get an error saying that

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "user_notifications_usernotification_sender_id_key" and DETAIL: Key
>   (sender_id)=(1) already exists. I used heroku to deploy my system and
>   Postgresql as my database.

I already tried to change my sender relationship from `OneToOneField` to `Foreignkey`, but I still get the same error.

python
models.py

```
class UserNotification(models.Model):
    sender= models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_sender',unique=True)
    receiver= models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_receiver',unique=False)
    concern_type= models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=CHOICES)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=255,blank=False)
    date_sent= models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
```

views.py

```
def send_notifications(request):# form that admin can send notification to a specific user.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SendNotificationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.sender = request.user
            receiver = instance.receiver
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request,'Your notification was sent successfully!')
            return redirect('send-notification-form')
    else:
        form = SendNotificationForm()
    template_name = ['user-forms/send-notification-form.html']
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,template_name,context)
def user_notifications(request): # notification module of users
    notifications   = UserNotification.objects.filter(receiver__exact=request
        .user).order_by('-date_sent')
    context = { 'notifications':notifications }
    template_name = ['notification.html']
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

forms.py

```
class SendNotificationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserNotification
        fields = ['receiver','concern_type','content']
```

Comment: Your `sender` field in your `UserNotification` model is `OneToOne`. That means any sender can only send a single `UserNotification`. I'm not sure why this appears to be letting one user send multiple `UserNotification`s on your local machine; it shouldn't be. (Note that this is a constraint on the _sender_, not the recipient.)

Comment: Yup, but I already tried to change my sender field in my Usernotification to foreignkey and it works on my local but when I deploy I still get the same error.

Comment: Well the code you're sharing here definitely has the issue I outlined above. If you're still having trouble when it's a `ForeignKey` please share _that_ code.

Comment: class UserNotification(models.Model):
    sender=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_sender',unique=False)
    receiver= models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_receiver',unique=False)
    concern_type= models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=CHOICES)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=255,blank=False)
    date_sent= models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

Comment: It woks and the user receives my notification multiple times on my local machine, but it wasn't working when I deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my error. I just reset my database and migrate it on heroku command